# Concatenate sparse matrices - ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to concatenate two sparse matrices (of the same number of rows) by rows.

So I tried to do this:

```
C = np.concatenate((A, B.T), axis=1)
```

where

- A is a `<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>` of (637, 46872) shape
- B is a `<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>` of (637, 37) shape

However, when I try to do this then I get the following error:

```
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

How can I do this then?

Comment: Do not use `np.concatenate` on sparse matrices.  Use `sparse.hstack` or `vstack`.

Comment: @hpaulj, ah yes, sorry quite silly mistake haha.